# Cannot extract element from a scalar - postgresql error

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm getting this error when trying to access data in a JSON object, does anybody know what it is causing it?

This is the query:

```
SELECT id, data FROM cities WHERE data->'location'->>'population' = '270816'
```

This is the JSON object:

```
location": {

"population": 270816,
"type": "city"

}
```

Any help would be really appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this `SELECT` to work in *Postgres* 9.3.1. Here's an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d49ed/1/0) which illustrates that.

Here is the *DDL* and `INSERT` statement I used in the *sqlfiddle*:

```
create table cities
(
  id serial,
  data json
);

insert into cities (data) VALUES
                ('{
                     "location": {
                                     "population": 270816,
                                     "type": "city"
                                 }
                  }'
                );
```

What version of Postgres are you using? How are you inserting the *JSON*? What's the *DDL* for your `cities` table?

It suspect it may be an issue with the way you are inserting the JSON data. Try inserting it similar to the way I am doing in the *sqlfiddle* above and see if that works for you. i.e. as a pure *SQL* string, but one with valid *JSON* inside, into a column defined as `json`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me. I insert the data using javascript and sequelize, the data comes from a json file that has many city objects. When I check the data in the database the structure is just the same as the one you show above.

Comment: Sure, no problem. What version of *Postgres*? What happens if you use *psql* and insert the data exactly as I have above into a table defined exactly the same way? Does that work? (I would expect it to, given that it worked in the *sqlfiddle*).

Comment: Hi, I'm using version 9.3, when i insert the data your way it works but I already knew it would work because I had tried that before, I think it's something to do with sequelize importing the data from the json file into the database, something occurs then that create this issue

Answer (score 0):

Just had what sounds like the same issue on Postgres 9.6.6.  Improper string escaping caused mysterious JSONB behavior.  Using pgAdmin4,

```
CREATE TABLE json_test (json_data JSONB);
INSERT INTO json_test (json_data) VALUES ('"{\"id\": \"test1\"}"');
INSERT INTO json_test (json_data) VALUES ('{"id": "test2"}');
SELECT json_data, json_data->>'id' as id FROM json_test;
```

returns the following pgAdmin4 output [showing baffling failure to find id test2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geTIu.png)  Turns out the pgAdmin4 display is misleading.  Situation becomes clear using text display from PSQL:

```
db=> CREATE TABLE json_test (json_data JSONB);
CREATE TABLE
db=> INSERT INTO json_test (json_data) VALUES ('"{\"id\": \"test1\"}"');
INSERT 0 1
db=> INSERT INTO json_test (json_data) VALUES ('{"id": "test2"}');
INSERT 0 1
db=> SELECT json_data, json_data->>'id' as id FROM json_test;
       json_data       |  id
-----------------------+-------
 "{\"id\": \"test1\"}" |
 {"id": "test2"}       | test2
(2 rows)
```

Where it is obvious that the first row was inserted as a string which just looks like JSON, not as a nested JSON object.